# What does xargs do if it's used without any parameter?

Tags: xargs

```
[user@notebook ~] echo -e '1\n2\n3\n4'
1
2
3
4
[user@notebook ~] echo -e '1\n2\n3\n4' | xargs
1 2 3 4
[user@notebook ~]
```

**My question:** So xargs removes the newlines if it's used without parameters?

Comment: I'm trying to resolve this same issue.  No matter how many new lines (`\n`), spaces, etc.  you add `xargs` wants to concatenate all the input when there is no argument.  Unless you use the `-0` option.  However, evne then `xargs` will only `echo` the input lines.  This is annoying because you have to remember to use `grep -z` and what about commands that don't a similar `-print0` option(?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quoting the manpage:

> **xargs** reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks (which can be protected with double or single quotes or a backslash)
>   or newlines, and executes the *command* (default is `/bin/echo`) one
>   or more times with any *initial-arguments* followed by items  read 
>   from  standard input.  Blank lines on the standard input are ignored.
>
> Because Unix filenames  can contain blanks and newlines, this
>   default behaviour is often problematic; filenames containing blanks
>   and/or newlines are incorrectly processed by `xargs`.  In these
>   situations it is better to use the `-0` option, which prevents such
>   problems.   When using this option you will need to ensure that the
>   program which produces the input for `xargs` also uses a null character
>   as a separator.  If that program is GNU `find` for example, the `-print0`
>   option does this for you.

Answer (score 6):

Without arguments `xargs` defaults to echoing out the parameters that are passed to it.

*from the man page*

> This manual page documents the GNU version of xargs.  xargs reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks (which can be protected  with  double  or  single quotes or a backslash) or newlines, and executes the command (default is `/bin/echo`) one or more times with any initial-arguments followed by items read from standard input.  Blank lines on the standard input are ignored.

Notice the bit about "...default is `/bin/echo`...".

#### Removal of newlines?

That's kind of the purpose of `xargs`. It takes a list of arguments, often split by spaces & newlines (can be split by other delimiters), and repackages them as a single argument, optimizing the arguments so that they fit within a ARG_MAX's worth of space.

Comment: It doesn't split by newline by default, it splits by sequences of space, tab or newline where single quote, double quote or backslash can escape the separators (and each others). To split by newline, you need either the GNU specific `-d $'\n'` or escape every blank and quote character except newline.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Without arguments, `xargs` replaces newlines with spaces, because it:

1. Bundles up all the whitespace-separated input items into a single space-separated list of up to `ARG_MAX` items; and
2. Passes that list to `/bin/echo`; which
3. Prints the list of items passed to it, on a single line.